Error shown in the count metrics not seen in the CloudWatch logs
I am seeing below Error and Success Count % metrics in the lambda monitoring tab. In order to check what exact error is being thrown by the lambda, I see the CW logs but dont see any error/exception. Also there are no timeouts as seen in other metrics of the lambda. Is it possible that the lambda threw error before calling the handleRequest() method and hence the no log was generated of the error in the CW logs but still its count appeared in the metrics?

